# Determining the distribution of random variable by observation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

We have two probability distributions $\mu, \nu$ on $\mathbb R$. There is a positive measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ with $$\mu(A) = \int_A f \text d\nu $$ for all Borel measurable $A$.

Let $X$ be a random variable whose distribution is $\mu$ or $\nu$. We want to determine which is right distribution after observing an instance of $X$. We have a following strategy:

1. Choose a Borel set $B$ a priori.
2. Observe $X$; after observation, we claim that $\mu$ is right if $X \in B$ and $\nu$ is right for $X \not\in B$.

The problem suddenly suggests the function $\phi$, as $$\phi(B,a) = a \mu(B^c) + (1-a)\nu (B)$$ for al fixed real number $a \in (0,1)$.

The problem says: describe the meaning of $\phi$, and for a given $a\in(0,1)$, find $B$ such that $\phi(B,a)$ is minimal.

Additionally, the problem asks: what is $f$, if both $\mu$ and $\nu$ admit positive probability density functions in $\mathbb R$?

However, I have no idea why the problem suggested such a function $\phi$ and what is $\phi$ having to do with guessing the distribution of $X$. Plus, why is problem asking what happens if $\mu,\nu$ admit density? I cannot see the link between the setting (guessing the distribution) and the actual thing that the problem is asking for.

Thanks in advance for any form of help, hint, or solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we phrase the problem as a hypothesis test, then we would call $\mu$ the null hypothesis and $\nu$ the alternative hypothesis.

There are two types of errors that may occur, when doing a hypothesis test. A type I error, which is when you reject the null hypothesis, even though it is true. This happens with probability
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{type I error}) &= \mathbb{P}(X \notin B \: | \: \mu \text{ is correct}) \\
&= \mu(B^c).
\end{align*}
And a type II error, which is when we fail to reject the null hypothesis, when the alternative is true, which happens with probability
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{type II error}) &= \mathbb{P}(X \in B \: | \: \nu \text{ is correct}) \\
&= \nu(B).
\end{align*}
We see now, that $\phi$ is a convex combination of these two probabilities, and that minimizing $\phi$ corresponds to minimizing the probability of both errors simultaneously. The value of $a$ determines wheter we assign a higher importance to reducing type I or II errors.

To minimize $\phi$, we write it out explicitly.

\begin{align*}
\phi(B,a) &= a\mu(B^c) + (1-a)\nu(B) \\
          &= \int_{B^c} a f \: d\nu + \int_{B} (1-a) \: d\nu \\
          &= \int_\mathbb{R} af1_{B^c} + (1-a)1_{B} \: d\nu
\end{align*}
To minimize the function inside the integral we must choose $B$ as
$$B = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \: | \: af(x) > 1-a \: \} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \: | \: f(x) > \frac{1-a}{a}  \}$$
Lastly we note that if both $\mu$ and $\nu$ have densities $g_\mu$ and $g_\nu$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, then since
$$\mu(A) = \int_A f \: d\nu = \int_A f g_\nu \: d\lambda$$
for all measurable sets $A$, we must have $g_\mu = f g_\nu$ or equivalently $f=\frac{g_\mu}{g_\nu}$. This means that in the case where the densities exist, our derived test is in fact a likelihood ratio test.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have a random variable $C \in \{0,1\}$, which indicates the 'class' of a sample.
That is, let
$$X \vert C = 1 \sim \mu$$
$$X \vert C = 0 \sim \nu$$

Now, you described that a sample is assigned an estimate of the class, let's say $\hat{C}$, in the following way
$$ \hat{C}\vert X = \mathbb{I}[X \in B]$$
with $\mathbb{I}$ being the indicator function.

Then we can ask, what is the probability that we do a misclassification, that is, what is the probability of $C \neq \hat{C}$?

Well, it is
$$\mathbb{P}[C \neq \hat{C}] = \mathbb{P}[C = 1, \hat{C} = 0] + \mathbb{P}[ C= 0 , \hat{C} = 1] = \mathbb{P}[C = 1, X \notin B] + \mathbb{P}[C = 0, X \in B].$$

I think from there you should be able to proceed.

**Edit**

Since you now got a full answer above anyway:

Assume that the marginal distribution of $C$ is $\mathcal{B}(1,a)$. This is thus a prior on the relative frequency of classes.
Then we have

$$ \mathbb{P}[C = 1, X \notin B] + \mathbb{P}[C = 0, X \in B] \\= \mathbb{P}[X \notin B \vert C =1] \mathbb{P}[C=1] + \mathbb{P}[X \in B \vert C =0] \mathbb{P}[ C=1] = a \mu(B^c) + (1-a) \nu(B) =\phi(a,B).$$

Thus, you can also interpret the weighting of type I/type II errors as choosing a prior probability.

Comment: +1. Interesting with a more Bayesian view of the problem. I think you can take it even further by considering the posterior probability
$$P(C=1 \: | \: X=x) = \frac{af(x)}{af(x) + 1-a} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1-a}{a}\frac{1}{f(x)}},$$
which is greater than $\frac12$ precisely when $f(x) > \frac{1-a}{a}$. So the test is also equivalent to taking the class with highest posterior probability.